# Unique representation, Bott & Tu, Poincaré's Lemma.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, differential-forms

On [page 34](http://www.math.toronto.edu/jcarlson/DFAT.pdf) where the author proves

> The maps  $\pi: \Bbb R ^n \times \Bbb R^1 \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $s: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^1$ ($x \mapsto (x,0))$,  induces isomoprhism. 
>       $$H^*(\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^1) \rightarrow H^*(\Bbb R^1)$$
>   in the de Rham cohomology.

he stated that

> Every form on $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R$ is uniquely a linear combination of the following two types.
>
> 1. $(\pi^* \phi ) f(x,t)$
> 2. $(\pi^* \phi) f(x,t) dt. $
>
> where **$\phi$ is a form on the base $\Bbb R^n$.**

I do not understand what is meant here. May someone elaborate? Is it what I think below?

---

We know a $k$-form is written *uniquely* as a sum of 
$$ \sum_{|I|=k-1} f_Idx_I dt + \sum_{|I|=k} f_I dx_I $$ 
such that $I$ is an increasing subset of $1$ to $n$. **It seems that $\phi = dx_I$**  otherwise we would **not have uniqueness**. Is this right?

Comment: $$\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_p\le n}g(i_1,\dots,i_p)=\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_p<n}g(i_1,\dots,i_p)+\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_{p-1}<n}g(i_1,\dots,i_{p-1},n)$$

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard, what exactly is that? We are working with differential forms...?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a differential $p$-form on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then $\alpha$ can be written in a unique way as $$\alpha=\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_p\le n}f_{i_1,\dots,i_p}dx_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i_p}.$$ Setting $$g(i_1,\dots,i_p):=f_{i_1,\dots,i_p}dx_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i_p}$$ in my previous comment yields $$\alpha=\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_p<n}f_{i_1,\dots,i_p}dx_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i_p}$$ $$+\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_{p-1}<n}f_{i_1,\dots,i_{p-1},n}dx_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i_{p-1}}\wedge dx_n.$$

Comment: Ok, thanks I agree with this part, but my concern now is *Uniqueness* . This is NOT true right? As i noted under Ted's comments.

Comment: The statement we need, I think, is this. In the notation of Bott and Tu p. 34, let $B$ be the canonical $C^\infty(\mathbb R^{n+1})$-basis of $\Omega^q(\mathbb R^{n+1})$, let $B_1$ be the set of those elements of $B$ which are of type (I), and define $B_2$ similarly. Then $B=B_1\cup B_2$. Do you agree with the statement, and with the fact that it's what's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, but I would recommend being a bit more explicit and not abusing notation. If you have a $k$-form $\omega$, then you can write 
$$\omega = \sum_{|I|=k-1}f_I(x,t)dx_I\,dt + \sum_{|J|=k} g_J(x,t)dx_J,$$
where you restrict, as you said, to increasing multi-indices. (In general, $\phi$ could be a combination $\sum h_I(x)dx_I$, but we can absorb the functions into the $f_I(x,t)$, and so on.)

Comment: Yes , sorry, i have edited.

Comment: actually I am concerned about uniqueness. Of the terms with no $dt$, If you let $\phi$ be as you described,  then say $f(x,t) = 2x$, 
 $$2x dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 $$  
Can be represented by $$\pi^*(dx_1dx_2x_3) f(x,t) $$ or  $$\pi^*(2x dx_1dx_2dx_3).$$

Comment: Yea, and as you noted yourself, the functions $h_I$ can be chosen to be absorbed in to $f_I$ or not, so there is some choice here.

Comment: I suspect that by uniqueness they mean the following: You can write $\omega$ uniquely as $\omega = \omega_1 + \omega_2$, where $\omega_1$ has $dt$ and $\omega_2$ has no $dt$. To make that rigorous, just say $\iota_{\partial/\partial t}\omega_2 = 0$, etc.